# How to indent multiple lines at once in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Is there any way to indent multiple lines in Pycharm? I tried highlighting multiple lines and pressing tab and ctrl+shift+i, but none of them seems to work.

P.S. Shift-tabbing works for me

Comment: Try selecting auto-indent in the code tab

Answer (score 1):

You can try `CTR + Alt + L`, and the whole script will be indented automatically！

Answer (score 0):

Move your cursor to above or below those lines. Use `shift` with up or down arrow to select lines. When you are done, press `Tab`